# Circle with fractions, different size and color

Tags: tikz-styles

I want to draw a circle and display some fractions. I wrote a code for a situation in which all parts have the same size and color. But what if i want the parts to different from each other (i.e. size and color)?

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5]{standalone}
\newcount\segmentsleft
\tikzset{pics/.cd,
circle fraction/.style args={#1/#2}{code={%
\segmentsleft=#1\relax
\pgfmathloop
\ifnum\segmentsleft<1\else
\ifnum\segmentsleft<#2 \edef\n{\the\segmentsleft}\else\def\n{#2}\fi
\begin{scope}[shift={(\pgfmathcounter,0)}]
\foreach \i [evaluate={\a=360/#2*(\i-1)+90;}] in {1,...,\n}
\fill[fill=purple,line width =1pt] (0,0) -- (\a:3/8) arc (\a:\a+360/#2:3/8) -- cycle;
\draw circle [line width =1pt,radius=3/8];
\ifnum#2>1
\foreach \i [evaluate={\a=360/#2*(\i-1);}] in {1,...,#2}
\draw (0,0) -- (90+\a:3/8);
\fi
\end{scope}
\advance\segmentsleft by-#2
\repeatpgfmathloop
}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=0.1pt]
 \foreach \numerator/\denominator [count=\y] 
 in {5/8}{
 %  \node at (-1/2,-\y) {$\frac{\numerator}{\denominator}$};
  \pic  at (0, -\y) {circle fraction={\numerator/\denominator}};
  }
  \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Like in the picture above. The crossed line should not be there

Comment: So it would be perfect if i can make 3 args for each part like this:

Comment: 1/8,purple ... 1/8, purple ... 1/4, red ... 1/8, purple ... 1/8, white ... 1/8, white ... 1/8, white

Comment: You can edit your question and add the information that you currently provide as comments (which is confusing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

[image]

This can be simply draw in one loop without defining `pic` images for pie segments:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i/\j/\k in {0/45/white,45/90/yellow,90/135/orange,135/150/red,
                    150/210/purple, 210/270/blue, 270/300/teal,300/360/white}
{
\draw[fill=\k] (0,0) -- (\i:2) arc (\i:\j:2);
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: And a nice selection of colors!